# Why wireless network list become unavailable after screensaver activity?

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, screensaver

Every time I resume my work after a screensaver, the wireless network list becomes unavailable. No listing at all. Wireless connection is activated all the way. What baffles me is that I can web browse exactly like before. Connection details shows I'm (still) connected to the same wireless network. Does anybody know how to refresh the wireless connection list in Xubuntu 16.04?

Addendum: I may have found A cause, my laptop's wireless hardware switch was off (i saw it in Windows, shamefully), and yet wireless was working in Xubuntu.

Comment: I am seeing this as well in plain Ubuntu 16.04 after resuming from suspend/sleep.

Comment: Possible duplicate of "Wifi doesn't work after suspend after 16.04 upgrade"

Comment: @SteveRoome WiFi works. It connects to known spots. We just can't see the list of available WiFi access points.

Comment: Some people told me i can log off (and relog in) or use the rfkill command. I don't mind doing any of those, but isn't Ubuntu supposed to refresh the list from time to time. Do anyone knows how i could change that interval?

Comment: @ipse lute Read the question and answer I quoted. It exactly replicates your issue and has a solution.